# Promise pending as gAPI geocode call

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, es6-promise, google-geocoding-api

from within a Google API maps places call, I also need to retreive place coords:

```
if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
  callback(data);
} else {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}
for (var i = 0; i < predictions.length; i++) {
  let coords = geocoder.geocode({
    'placeId': predictions[i].place_id,
  },
  function (responses, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      var lat = responses[0].geometry.location.lat()
      var lng = responses[0].geometry.location.lng()
      return (lat + '#' + lng)
      //CONSOLE LOG HERE IS WORKING the RETURN NOT
    }
  });

  console.log(coords);
  data.results.push({
    id: predictions[i].place_id,
    text: predictions[i].description,
    value: coords,
  });
}
```

unluckily I get "PROMISE" value, rather than coords string one.
I can't get the way to return and unwrap the promise :(

can you help me?

tyvm

Comment: Just use `promise.then(value => /* your code */)` or `async`/`await`

Comment: NO MATTER what I do, I keep receiving  _async coords() { Unexpected token (42:34)_
`async coords() { new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ...`

                                }
                            }

Comment: Instead of trying not to receive Promises, embrace them! Your code is asynchronous, you could handle it with callbacks or Promises (which is better). I'll write an answer for you

Comment: LOL :D I just don't know HOW to embrace them! :D https://jsfiddle.net/56bp4xz2/ PROMISE IS NOT DEFINED :(

Comment: can you try the code in my answer?

Comment: I did sir, see jsfiddel :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is asynchronous and there is no possible way of making it synchronous, so instead of trying to return something else than a `Promise`, just adapt your code:

```
if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
  callback(data);
} else {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

const coords = await Promise.all(
    predictions.map(x => geocoder.geocode({
        'placeId': x.place_id
      })).map(x => x.then(responses => {
        const lat = responses[0].geometry.location.lat()
        const lng = responses[0].geometry.location.lng()
        return (lat + '#' + lng)
      })).map(x => x.then(coords => ({
        value: coords
      }))));

data.results = predictions.map(({ place_id, description }) => ({ place_id, description })).map((x, i) => ({ ...x, ...coords[i] }));

console.log(data.results);
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test it so it may contain mistakes

Note: this code implies that the surrounding function is declared as `async` which means it also returns a `Promise` so you have to adapt the rest of your code as well.

Comment: ty, I was trying to edit the original one taken from here: https://jsfiddle.net/angelmarde/perqpp9f/2/